# web api routing with action and id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new in using web api and I am trying to call a specific method in my controller.

I have

global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

the WebApiConfig class with these routings

```
 // Web API routes
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "ActionApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new
       {
          id = RouteParameter.Optional
       }
  );



 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
       action="DefaultAction",
       id = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
 );
```

and my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPatSummary(string PatId)
{
   PatientSummary Pat = new PatientSummary();

   HttpResponseMessage Response = new HttpResponseMessage();
   string yourJson = Pat.GetPatient(PatId);
   Response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, yourJson);
   return Response;
}

[ActionName("DefaultAction")] //Map Action and you can name your method with any text
public IHttpActionResult GetPatient(int id)
{
    Object Obj = new object();

    if (Obj!=null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(Obj);
}
```

the URL I am using is

http://localhost/mdmwapi/api/MdmwPatientController/GetPatSummary/sgdgdgddhdhd1334254

but I get this error
A path segment cannot contain two consecutive parameters. They must be separated by a '/' or by a literal string.

I am getting nut :-)

Comment: what is `mdmwapi` portion of url ?

Comment: is the project name

Comment: you should remove this part and try again what happen, because its not the part of url

Comment: I did and ai get a 404 error as the url in IIS is registered to be http://localhost/mdmwapi  I can try to re-create the virtual directory to be http://localhost/api

Comment: So I recreate the virtual directory to localhost/api so that the full URL is now http://localhost/api/MdmwPatientController/GetPatSummary/sgdgdgddhdhd1334254  but I get the same error

Additional information: A path segment cannot contain two consecutive parameters. They must be separated by a '/' or by a literal string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use attribute routing

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MdmwPatientController/GetPatSummary/{PatId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPatSummary(string PatId)
{
    PatientSummary Pat = new PatientSummary();

    HttpResponseMessage Response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    string yourJson = Pat.GetPatient(PatId);
    Response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, yourJson);
    return Response;
}
```

then you can request it using

```
http://localhost/api/MdmwPatientController/GetPatSummary/yourpatid
```

also you can map any url using attribute routing this way

Comment: Ok so can I delete the routing from my WebApiConfig?

Comment: keep defaults and remove others

Answer (score 0):

the solution is a combination of a new route and a mistake in the URL

the new routes are now these ones

```
// Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();   

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
        (
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new
         {
             id = RouteParameter.Optional
         }
         );


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiMethodCall",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{PatId}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller= "MdmwPatient",
                    action= "GetPatSummary"    
                    }
                );
```

and the error in the URL was that although the controller class name is MdmwPatientController I have to omit the "controller" suffix when calling from the test client, so the correct url is

http://localhost/mdmwapi/api/MdmwPatient/GetPatSummary/sgdgdgddhdhd1334254

Comment: I want to thank Mostafiz because his suggestions lead me to figure it out my solution and for this reason I am accepting his answer